# where to save a file in cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin, save

noobiest question ever:
I'm trying to work with python via cygwin on my pc laptop - I have a file (foo.py) but python can't find it. The error it's giving me is:

```
$ chmod +x foo.py
chmod: cannot access `foo.py': No such file or directory
```

Is there a special location within the Cygwin folder that I need to save my foo.py?
Thanks!
AP

Comment: if you create a `python` file it should be in `cygwin/home/username` otherwise try `ls -R ` or `find` linux tool. You can also try `find -name foo.py` it will print out the path of `foo.py`.

Comment: And you can add foo.py to the PATH env var so you don't have to include its full path each time by using this: `SET PATH=$PATH:/home/YourUsername/Desktop` this command assumes that you have foo.py in your desktop else change the directory only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not python that can't find your file, it's the chmod command. C drive is mapped to /cygdrive/c in Cygwin, and D drive is mapped to /cygdrive/d and so on and so forth.

Are you in the same directory as the file when you are running chmod?

If your file is at C:\mycode\python\foo.py then you should either change to that directory first -

```
$ cd c:
$ cd mycode/python/
```

or as @Ahmed mentioned above, you could also run the command as

```
$ chmod +x /cygdrive/c/mycode/python/foo.py
```

But you only need chmod if your python script starts with

```
#!/bin/python
```

To execute such a file, you'd say

```
$ /cygdrive/c/mycode/python/foo.py
```

Or if you are in the same directory

```
./foo.py
```

If the first line of the python script isn't "#!/bin/python" then you can skip the chmod and just type

```
python /cygdrive/c/mycode/python/foo.py
```

Answer (score 1):

You go right click on foo.py figure out its full path then do this:

```
chmod +x foos-full-directory/foo.py
```

And this should work for you and btw its not Python problem it's your pwd other than the foo.py working directory and you even didn't use python word in your command.